# How to redirect my homepage

Tags: template-redirect

My wordpress theme uses templates but I want to temporarily redirect the homepage which uses the template "page.php" to a category page which uses a template file.

Can I use a redirect plugin to achieve this? If so I don't know how because i cant specify the url.

thanks

Comment: Are you saying you want to use the category template file for your home page temporarily? Or are you wanting user's who visit your home page to be temporarily redirected to a category page? Unclear from your question.

Comment: I want users who visit the homepage to temporarily be redirected to a category page.

Comment: K, and why can't you specify the URL? If you're just redirecting to a category page, can you not just use `https://yoursite.com/category/post-name`?

Answer (score 0):

Two options that I've used to solve this issue:

1. Homepage template file
   Create a `front-page.php` file, which is the template file used by WordPress for your homepage, it takes priority over `page.php`, see [this](https://developer.wordpress.org/files/2014/10/Screenshot-2019-01-23-00.20.04.png) for more reading on page template priority. In your `front-page.php` file, add the following code:

```php
<?php
header('Location: https://yoursite.com/subpage');
die();
```

2. 301 Redirect Plugin
   A plugin I've used before to manage redirects: [301 Redirects](https://wordpress.org/plugins/eps-301-redirects/), works pretty much as you described.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a different template file for the homepage. WordPress has a [template hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/templates/template-hierarchy/) from general to more specific. You should add a home.php to your theme and you don't need to redirect anything.

If you want the homepage to look like the category page you just need to copy the file and rename it to home.html (this is new to me, used to be home.php). There are several other ways to assign a template to a specific page or post as described in the support article. I assume Category has some loop features that you like, I would just use that code from that template and keep pressing forward with your theme and template development.

Comment: If you take a look in the diagram in the article you linked to, `home.php` doesn't take hierarchy over `page.php`, which is the page template OP is using for their home page. `home.php` (counterintuitively) is not necessarily the home page template, but the main posts page (it will be the home page if it's set up that way in Settings).

Comment: `.php` file extensions do also function the same way as `.html` template files it seems too, didn't actually know you could use `.html` files for your template! Thanks for sharing